# Facebook SDK Login in Iphone Application

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using FaceBook SDK for iOS.

For login a UIWebView comes and we have to add username and password. I don't want to login like this.

Can the login be done in the background or without opening the UIWebView if user provide the username and password from iOS Application?

Answer (score 2):

FaceBook's SDK doesn't allow that.. they've implemented the oauth login method so that the user don't need to give username and password to the application, user directly input the credentials in the web view and get authenticated via the fb servers. But in response app receives an access token which it can save and and use for future transactions and user don't need to enter his username or password again. This tutorial might be helpful in this regard:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Delegate methods are available in the SDK in which you can save the access token.

Comment: as ebuddy application save the username and password on mobile and application login to facebook in background...I want something like that

Comment: as my application has its own username and password and want if he/she login into application also automatic login into facebook if he/she already provide the detail

Comment: sorry... didn't use ebuddy yet!! but after getting access token once u can login user in background afterwards.

Comment: but in that case user has to login every time he/she login into application...
But I want if he/she provide aunthentic detail already then should not be enter username/password for login everytime ...........ebuddy  is a mobile chat application

Answer (score 0):

I am using FaceBook Sdk Older Version, in this u can use of Session through this only one time it will ask for login,

http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

this tutorial works like u want

Comment: one time means... I want like that if I have username password saved in DB then user no need to login ...it login automatically in background

Comment: how do know the username before login.  atleast onetime he need to be login know?

Comment: one more issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141703/fbconnect-api-response-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

you cannot save the retrieve the facebook username and password and you are not suppose to save it in your db due to the privacy issue, what can you do is when the first time your user is login in permisssion ask for offline_access and then you will get an access token which will be valid for indefinitely, you can save this access_token.

Comment: But I think we can save the password within application locally on iphone in any file or in sqlite

Comment: Hi Amit, with any open id or a login like this, for example you must have seen that facebook ask to enter the gmail id and pasword to check who all your gmail contact are in facebook, they also don't store your password, as an user will you give your password to any random developer, you will not. Also it is good practice to not store it. If all your need can be taken care of by the access_token why you need to store the password, what is your use case what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.XYZ.com";

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [web loadRequest:request];

}



-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{


     [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"var field = document.getElementById('ctl00_txtPassword');"  
     "field.value='%@';",password]];  

     [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var field = document.getElementById('ctl00_txtUsername');"  
     "field.value='%@';",username]]; 

}


-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
{

         [self.web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"fnLogin();"];  

}
```

It Solve your Problem very easily.