# fbconnect ios iphone error on login page

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook

I am using fbconnect for iOS in Iphone application

When I am open the login using code:

```
[facebookObj authorize:fbPermissions delegate:self];
```

but in the UIWebView I got the error message
**"An Error Occurred. Please try again later"**

What I am missing. Please help

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AtFirst thing, have u do these thing, allocate FBclass with ur APPId,  in DidLoad then

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
fbPermissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"read_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];
  }
  return self;
  }
```

Atlast for login IBACTION

```
  [_facebook authorize:fbPermissions delegate:self];
```

Dont Forget ur AppID

Comment: my problem solved ... thanks dear... actually in a function I have set the appid BLANK by mistake ...thanks for this help... I have a another issue related to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115015/facebook-sdk-login-in-iphone-application

Comment: Thats i know, mee too miss the same atfirst.   pls check the right mark for this answer if you satisfied

Comment: ya sure.... one more issue . . .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141703/fbconnect-api-response-in-iphone

Answer (score 2):

check if your app is not in **SANDBOX** mode

Comment: If you are in sandbox, just be sure that the account you are logged in with on the device has been given a role with permission to use the app (as a tester/developer).