# Facebook gives error when trying to share from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

After some googling and stackoverflow surfing, i didn't find any description of my problem, and it would be great if somebody help me

I am making an app on iPhone(supporting 4.0 and up), with FB share function.

Everything works just great untill I do next things:

I will login in my app. Sharing works awesome whatever i'll do. But if I log out from the website on my PC, and try again to summon the FB dialog window, it will show the following:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
```

Well, I don't really get what it is related to... Hope somebody can help me with that! Any ideas will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Is this error coming once FBDialog appears or before it?

Comment: It appears on the FBDialog, the one that usually would contain textView for comment share. But now it contains just the blue navBar with Error on it, Okay button, and X button on left top corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you allocate FBDialog with correct AppID.This is a usual mistake, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138607/fbconnect-ios-iphone-error-on-login-page)